# How to fix bs4 select error: 'TypeError: __init__() keywords must be strings'

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm writing a script that uses a post request and gets an XML in return. I need to parse that XML to know if the post request was accepted or not.
I'm using bs4 to parse it and it worked fine until about a week ago when I started to get an error I didn't get before:

```
TypeError: __init__() keywords must be strings
```

I'm using bs4's select function in other parts of the same file without getting this error, and I can't find anything about it online.
At first I thought it was a version issue, but I tried both python3.7 and 3.6 and got the same error.

This is the code used to produce the error:

```
res = requests.post(url, data = body, headers = headers)
logging.debug('Res HTTP status is {}'.format(res.status_code))

try:
    res.raise_for_status()
    resSoup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'xml')
    # get the resultcode from the resultcode tag
    resCode = resSoup.select_one('ResultCode').text
```

Full error messege:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "EbarInt.py", line 292, in <module>
    resCode = resSoup.select_one('ResultCode').text
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1345, in select_one
    value = self.select(selector, namespaces, 1, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1377, in select
    return soupsieve.select(selector, self, namespaces, limit, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\soupsieve\__init__.py", line 108, in select
    return compile(select, namespaces, flags).select(tag, limit)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\soupsieve\__init__.py", line 50, in compile
    namespaces = ct.Namespaces(**(namespaces))
TypeError: __init__() keywords must be strings
```

When I check res.text type I get class 'str' as expected.

When I log `res.text` I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><soap:Header><wsa:Action>Trackem.Web.Services/CreateOrUpdateTaskResponse</wsa:Action><wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:3ecae312-d416-40a5-a6a3-9607ebf28d7a</wsa:MessageID><wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:6ab7e354-6499-4e37-9d6e-61219bac11f6</wsa:RelatesTo><wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To><wsse:Security><wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-6b84a16f-327b-42db-987f-7f1ea52ef802"><wsu:Created>2019-01-06T10:33:08Z</wsu:Created><wsu:Expires>2019-01-06T10:38:08Z</wsu:Expires></wsu:Timestamp></wsse:Security></soap:Header><soap:Body><CreateOrUpdateTaskResponse xmlns="Trackem.Web.Services"><CreateOrUpdateTaskResult><ResultCode>OK</ResultCode><ResultCodeAsInt>0</ResultCodeAsInt><TaskNumber>18000146</TaskNumber></CreateOrUpdateTaskResult></CreateOrUpdateTaskResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Side note: you really want to leave decoding to Unicode to the XML parser, use `res.content`, not `res.text`. This is not the cause of your current problem, however.

Comment: actually, the text method is the one that uses the encoding the parser guessed, the content method returnes bytes instead of a string.

Comment: Yes, but XML contains its own encoding information, and the XML parser will pick up on that. HTTP servers can easily get it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: BeautifulSoup 4.7.1 has been released, fixing the default-namespace issue. See the [release notes](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/CHANGELOG). You probably would want to upgrade just for the performance fixes.

*Original answer:*

---

You must have upgraded to BeautifulSoup 4.7, which replaced the simple and limited internal  CSS parser with the [`soupsieve` project](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/), which is a far more complete CSS implementation.

It is that project that has an issue with the default namespace attached to one of the elements in your response:

```xml
<CreateOrUpdateTaskResponse xmlns="Trackem.Web.Services">
```

The XML parser used to build the BeautifulSoup object tree correctly communicates that as the `None` -> `'Trackem.Web.Services'` mapping in the namespace dictionary, but the `soupsieve` code required that all namespaces have a prefix name (`xmlns:prefix`) with the default namespace marked with an empty string, not `None`, leading to this bug. I've reported this as [issue #68 to the `soupsieve` project](https://github.com/facelessuser/soupsieve/issues/68).

You don't need to use `select_one` at all here, you are not using any CSS syntax beyond an element name. Use `soup.find()` instead:

```
resCode = resSoup.find('ResultCode').text
```

Comment: does soup find has the same bug? how do i downgrade to the previous version? can't change the prefixes of namespaces

Comment: @youngmarx: no, `.find()` does not expect CSS selectors, and doesn't use the new soupsieve project. You could downgrade with `pip install -I beautifulsoup4<4.7.0` but you really don't need to here. The BeautifulSoup and soupsieve authors are aware of the issue and already working on how best to fix this, but your specific usecase is not affected anyway.